# iOS Simulator - Doesn't show 100% of the screen?

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios-simulator

So this is my first time ever using the iOS simulator, because I want to learn how to make iOS apps.
So eventually I dragged a few labels etc. into the storyboard just to try (before learning obj-c)

This is what the storyboard looks like:
[image: screen 1]

This is what it looks like in the simulator:
[image: screen 2]

By the way I can't go the left nor right, only up and down.

Comment: You need to use constraints to force those views to stay in one place relative to the screen size. Check out [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) for how to use constraints and autolayout.

Comment: you are using the new site classes. refer to developer.apple.com to learn how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use auto layout,  also you can bring up the preview of the phone screen to see how the storyboard translates to the actual phone or simulator screen.  What it looks like on the storyboard does not directly relate to how it will look on the sim or actual device

Answer (score -1):

Use hotkeys:

CMD+1 for scale 100%

CMD+2 for scale 75%

CMD+3 for scale 50%

Or you can set it in simulator main menu - Window->Scale

Comment: If you have a look on the status bar it is apparent that this is not the problem.

Comment: Stil doesn't work, yes it zoomed out. But the label stays the same position :/

Comment: @AndreasHolt you need setup autolayout constraints for you labels, text fields and etc... Start learning Objective C & Swift from reading books :)

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko thanks! it works now, I just disabled autolayout. Oh by the way, do you recommend any Objective C and Swift books :D?

Comment: @AndreasHolt Do not disable autolayout! _Learn_ autolayout.

Comment: @matt ohh okay! thanks for the tip, I will enable it again :)

Comment: @AndreasHolt Reason is, devices are all different sizes. Your interface needs to _adapt_ to each size as it appears. Autolayout is how you do that. You have been given very good comments / answers telling you what to do. Take them seriously.